# Rails + Unicorn Issue - DalliError: Unable to unmarshal value: undefined class/module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, shopify, unicorn, dalli

I have a Rails 3.1 app, which utilizes the Shopify API gem to fetch some external data via ActiveResource. We store these ActiveRecord model objects in Memcached via Dalli, and then read in again when needed.

We can successfully read in this data when running the Thin webserver, and everything works fine. However, once I setup Unicorn as the webserver then I continue to get the following error when reading the model object from Memcached:

```
Cache read: shopcache_987102
DalliError: Unable to unmarshal value: undefined class/module ShopifyAPI::Order::ClientDetails
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 395ms
```

This does not happen on every read, but regularly enough to be a big problem. It only happens when we spawn more than 1 Unicorn worker process.

Below is my unicorn.rb file:

```
worker_processes 3
timeout 30
preload_app true

after_fork do |server, worker|
  #Re-connect to ActiveRecord
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to ActiveRecord')
  end
end
```

We also have the following activated:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

If I only spawn up a single Unicorn worker_process (worker_processes 1) then all works fine. I have tried setting config.threadsafe! in application.rb and this does not help with multiple workers.

It seems that the needed class/module is not being required, and I cannot work out why.

EDIT:
I've also added the following to my applicaton.rb file to try and add the gem to the autoload path of rails, without success:

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

I've also added to the application_controller.rb require_dependency 'shopify_api' like so:

```
require 'current_shop_detail'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include CurrentShopDetail
  require_dependency 'shopify_api'

end
```

but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to do a require_dependency, seeing as the missing class is: ShopifyAPI::Order::ClientDetails

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: My config is the same except I don't use any before_fork block and thus do not disconnect from the db. Anyway, there's [**this dalli issue**](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/227) that might help you.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Klemm, I'll give adding **require_dependency "shopify_api"** a try in my Controller and report back. Other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I've removed the before_block from unicorn.rb as it seems unessesary, and also tried multiple blog suggestions around autoloading and require_dependency, but neither solves the underlying problem. Have Edited my question with these details